# Nuget Grpc.Core package versions

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, grpc-c#

Noticed that there is a [Grpc.Core nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Core/2.23.0) **v2.23.0**. Few months ago I used (as I thought the latest package) **v1.22.0**. Checked [GRPC releases](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/releases), the latest now is v1.23.1. I would expect Grps.Core to correspond the grpc version.

Why the version was changed to 2.*.*. ? Are there any significant changes?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why the version was changed to 2... ?

Because it took a breaking change, just for .NET.

> Are there any significant changes?

Yes - for *some* users. There are two breaking changes:

- The references to `System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerator<T>` (from `System.Interactive.Async`) have been removed
- A new base class `ChannelBase` has been introduced

The first of these changes is because [`IAsyncEnumerator<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iasyncenumerator-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) is now part of the standard library, but it's different to the version in `System.Interactive.Async`. Basically the old version of Grpc.Core / Grpc.Core.Api wouldn't play nicely with that.

The second of the changes it to provide better commonality between the pure-.NET implementation (`Grpc.Net.Common` etc) and the existing Google implementation (Grpc.Core).

Many users - particularly those who don't use streaming calls - will be able to just rebuild. If you *do* use streaming calls, and particularly if you've abstracted them via `IAsyncEnumerator<T>`, you may need to do a bit of work to upgrade.

It's important to note that if you're using any dependencies that in turn depend on Grpc.Core 1.x, you *cannot* use Grpc.Core 2.x in the same project until those dependencies have updated. (For example, all the Google Cloud client libraries currently depend on 1.x. We're planning to take a major version bump ourselves before the end of 2019 to then depend on 2.x.)

There are details in [proposal L57](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L57-csharp-new-major-version.md).

Answer (score 0):

For those of you wondering how to compare the gRPC .NET releases to the gRPC core releases, this excerpt from the proposal mentioned in @JonSkeets's answer should help.

> Therefore we will make both changes at the same time and release the
> next gRPC C# version as v2.23.0 (instead of v1.23.0).
>
> We chose version v2.23.0 instead of v2.0.0 so that the minor version
> number can still be used for comparing how old a given release is
> relative to all other gRPC implementations. E.g. gRPC C# 2.24.x will
> be released together with gRPC C++ 1.24.x.
>
> NO protocol changes are proposed between gRPC C# version 2.x and 1.x -
> both versions will be fully interoperable with each other and also
> with all other gRPC implementations.